# How to deal with concurrent processes working in MariaDB

Tags: sql, architecture, mariadb

We have an application that during the day will collect events and process them once or twice per day. But we have one database and two instances of the application so we are looking how to make sure that every event is processed once.

The events will contain the ID of the registration, and once or twice per day we want to process every registration that had an event. I believe that this means that we should store every event with the current timestamp. But I am stuck figuring out how to process them taking into account the duplicate instances.

One way is to add column processedTimestamp, an instance will `SELECT` a row where that column is `NULL` and `UPDATE` it to the current time. But I believe that this workflow will not definitively prevent the two instances from processing the same registration. They could both do the `SELECT` before the first `UPDATE` happens.

Another way I thought of was to start a transaction so that the all the events from a registration are locked and another instance can't get to them, but I feel like this isn't really what transactions are meant for.

This seems like a common problem to have when dealing with multiple instances, but what is the solution?

Comment: Is there some reason not to process events immediately?  It seems like the delay until "once or twice per day" is adding complexity.

Comment: No, processing them will send out communication so we want to batch that up instead of spamming them with twenty messages in a minute :-)

Comment: The alternative is to send out the message on the first occurrence, but remember when that email was sent.  Then don't send any further messages for at least N hours.  (N=24?)  (Or is that where you were going with the Timestamp?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOR UPDATE` may be a key component in your processing:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT (the rows you might process) FOR UPDATE;
do the processing
UPDATE (the rows you decided to process);
COMMIT;
```

This pattern tends to turn a conflict into a delay.  That is, the rows selected will not be available to any other process until after the `COMMIT`.  At that point, the other process would see that the rows have been processed and skip them.

You should not allow a `BEGIN...COMMIT` to run for more than a few seconds.

I don't see any need for a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: The issue is that the processing is done outside the SQL server in a Java application.

Comment: @Bob - That could still be done.  But it would need the four database calls I mention.  However, this would require all the work to be done in a single process  / thread / whatever.  Counterexample:  a web site that fetches accounting data on one page, but does not do the `UPDATE` until another web page.

Comment: Ah I see, and then I can use SKIP LOCKED to only SELECT rows that are available to process. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob - Is the question about SQL Server?  Or about MariaDB?

Comment: We are using MariaDB.

Comment: @Bob - Hmmm... `SKIP LOCKED` (or `NOWAIT`?) might be a good addition for _this_ application.  I assume it does not really matter _which_ rows you pick up for processing.  Further note:  `NOWAIT`/`SKIP LOCKED` are not available until 10.3/8.0

Comment: Yes, the order doesn't matter.